# iBeacon Dynamic Minor Value

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, bluez

I am using a Raspberry Pi as an iBeacon by creating a LaunchService that runs on startup executing the following (using BlueZ):

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0006 40 [...] 00
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x000A 01
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E [...] 02 C0 00 00 00 00 C5 00
```

So far this has worked beautifully. The service runs and as long as the Pi is powered, the iBeacon is advertised.

Now I would like to send some Information with the advertising data. I have a brightness sensor wired up to the Pi that simply returns `true` if a certain threshold of brightness has been exceeded.

My idea is to use the Minor identifier and use `1` to represent "it is bright" and `0`to represent "it is dark". My app can then interpret this without having to poll the Pi via a network request what the current sensor status is.

But since I set the advertisement package statically, I won't be able to use this approach going forward I believe.

I have no idea how else to do this however, so I was hoping someone might have some insight and could point me in the right direction.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.  You can simply re-issue those commands, specifically the last one:

`sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E [...] 02 C0 00 00 00 00 C5 00`

Just change the last byte before the C5 above to be 01 if you want to send out a minor of 1, and change it back to 00 if you want to send out a minor of 0.

Comment: So I would write a script that periodically checks the sensor value and reissues the command based on that?

Comment: Yes exactly.  It is unclear how you read the sensor, but if you can post an example I can show a shell script that dynamically changes the beacon transmission value.

Comment: Thanks! I worked it out using crontab and wiringPi! :)